# Android Application Activity NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I'm new to android development and stackoverflow, but I have a little experience in programming. I'm trying to run a a really basic application on the android emulator, and I get the above mentioned error report. I have narrowed the problem to be one of these lines of code, but from what I saw on web it looks like I'm using these methods correctly. I know the error is in here somewhere because I ran the code without it and it worked. I hope I'm being specific enough (I'm also open to any comments on the usage of this site).

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);      
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
        }
    });
    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the stack trace from the logcat:

```
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main   
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Process: j.G.thenewboston, PID: 1851    
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{j.G.thenewboston/j.G.thenewboston.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException  
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at j.G.thenewboston.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-18 08:51:59.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Thanks a lot for any help guys

Comment: Error Stack please...

Comment: Post your log please.

Comment: 1) please correct your title.  The code compiles but does not run.  2) post the stack trace of the crash from logcat, a critically important tool that informs you why it crashed

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you run a 'Clean & Build' in your IDE? Often a project can become out of sync with it's XMLs and the solution can be as simple as cleaning and rebuilding. Otherwise though we really are going to need to see the logcat.

Comment: Clarification: You can get your log cat by going to your sdk/tools directory and running monitor.bat on windows, or some IDEs have built in logs.

Comment: Hey Rudi, thanks for your help. I just cleaned and rebuilt, and got the same error message. I added my logcat to the post, does that help?

Comment: What is at line 34? Something there is `null`.

Comment: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: It looks like one of your `add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);` is returning null, hence `add` is null and can't have `setOnClickListener()` called on it. How are your Id's declared in the layout XML?

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong with that?

Comment: android:id="@+id/bAdd"

Comment: That's from my fragment_main.xml tab

Comment: I am a little confused. Is this your `Fragment` class or an `Activity`? Because it looks like you've overridden the `onCreate` from an `Activity` subclass. If this is your Activity then we might need to see where your `Fragment` class is defined and how it's declared in your activity layout xml. It might be worth [having a read of the fragment API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: @JonGor - I've added an answer with some things to try. Let me know how that goes and I'll update my answer if anything needs changing.

Comment: I found my mistake, the answer was in the API guide. I had wrongly placed the declarations of the button ids. Thanks a lot for all your help, you guys are really helpful and I appreciate it very much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, it looks like the following is returning null and setting `add` to null;

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);      
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) // Line 34
```

So on line 34 where you call `setOnClickListener` it is throwing the `NullPointerException` where you are trying to interact with your null object.

If those IDs are from your `PlaceholderFragment` layout, then they may not be accessible from your `Activity` class yet when the `findViewByID` is called. When you call `commit()` on your fragment, the action is scheduled but not carried out immediately. As such, you can't guarantee that those methods will ever find anything.

Any code initializing/manipulating the `View`s from your `PlaceholderFragment` layout really needs to be in your `PlaceholderFragment` class to prevent this from happening.

Comment: That is not a fix. commit method is an async task, even when you push your fragment and (bad practice) you try to set your objects of your fragment from outside of it, you might have a chance to get a null pointer because your fragment might not be committed yet. Edit: Async task was a bad description to use here, more precisely scheduled task.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu - Yea, your right. I just wanted to know whether it changed/prevented the issue. Technically the initialization/manipulation of add/subtract/display should be done in the PlaceholderFragment class. Updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably crashing because you work with fragments and your findViewById needs something like

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Edit: Replace this with your onCreate

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.symbollist_author_articles_fragment_layout, container, false);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        subtract = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);      
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }
```

Comment: I tried adding rootView before my findViewById method, bit it wouldn't compile; it gave me a "rootView cannot be resolved message". Any idea on that? Thanks for your help

Comment: I edited the code, please check it out. But you should at least post your class so that we can see what it extends.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {. That's the class. If there is any other important information I would be happy to post it, I'm just not sure as to what is the important stuff. I entered the code you edited here  (thank you) but it gave me errors at the onCreateView arguments and "View rootView" Statement. I don't know these statements so I wasn't really sure what to do with that...

Comment: Yea well, then it's not a fragment. It says a null pointer exception in your logs. What's on line 34 of your Main Activity? Should be something null in onCreate()